# Query to Generate New Column for Parent Each Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a simple table with hierarchical data:

```
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| id | name     | parent | level |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| 1  | province | Null   | 1     |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| 2  | city     | 1      | 2     |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| 3  | fire     | 2      | 3     |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
| 4  | ems      | 2      | 3     |
+----+----------+--------+-------+
```

I'm trying to build a recursive query to add a new column for each level. Like so:

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| id | level_1  | level_2 | level_3 |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| 1  | Province | Null    | Null    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| 2  | Province | City    | Null    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| 3  | Province | City    | Fire    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
| 4  | Province | City    | EMS     |
+----+----------+---------+---------+
```

I not sure how to approach this, I'm not that great with CTE queries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this is rather complicated.  I am thinking of using `union all` with separate queries for each level:

```
select t1.id, t1.name as level_1, null as level_2, null as level_3
from t t1 
where level = 1
union all
select t2.id, t1.name, t2.name, null
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.parent = t1.id
where t2.level = 2
union all
select t3.id, t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.parent = t1.id join
     t t3
     on t3.parent = t2.id
where t3.level = 3;
```